# Going from viewcontroller to tabbar's view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

[image]

Hi, this is my storyboard , i wanna go from First view controller to LoggedinViewController.

Im normally using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"s1" sender:self];
```

but if i add tab bar controller this line is not working , how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following if you have embedded into navigation controller.

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Story_Board_Name" bundle:nil];
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TABid"];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Or try this

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Story_Board_Name" bundle:nil];
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TABid"];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"s1" sender:self];
```

Comment: What If the `LogedInViewController` is embedded with a `UINavigationController`? In this case upper code is not working. In my scenario with this code, it bring me to the `UITabbarController`, but can't go to other tab, by pressing on them. It looks freeze. What would be the solution for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give your tabbarcontroller an identifier from the storyboard, the do something like this

```
 UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your_Story_Board_Name" bundle:nil];
 TabViewController *tabBarController = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TAB_Identifier"];
 [self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

first give "tabbarid" to that tab inside storyboard

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarid"];
    tabBarController1.selectedIndex = 1;
    [self presentViewController:tabBarController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```